# CodeAnaysis won't recognize word "color"

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

Maybe the stupid question, but why CodeAnalysis put a warning: "Warning CA1704 Correct the spelling of 'Сolor' in member name 'BaseHead.ActiveСolor()' or remove it entirely if it represents any sort of Hungarian notation", on the member "Public Property ActiveСolor As Color", sure name of structure "System.Drawing.Color" is spelled correctly, but what is wrong with the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting, at first I was not able to reproduce your problem. However after I tried with copying your "ActiveColor" directly from StackOverflow, I had the same issue.
It seems like there is some wierd charachter between the "e" of Active and the "C" of Color (however I did not yet quite figure out what exactly is the problem).

But I wrote a ConsoleApp that shows the problem:

```
class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var baseHead = new BaseHead();
         Console.WriteLine(nameof(baseHead.ActiveColor) == nameof(baseHead.ActiveСolor));
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }

   public class BaseHead
   {
      public string ActiveColor()
      {
         // Version I typed in myself
         return "";
      }

      public string ActiveСolor()
      {
         // Version I copy/pasted from SO
         return "";
      }
   }
```

As you can see, there are 2 methods that apparently look the same, but the compiler doesn't think so and you can run the program.
In the Main method i just compared the names of the two methods and the result is false.

So I think to solve your Issue, try to rename your current method name with one that you write from scratch. If that doesn't work, try to copy it from my sample and see if that solved it.

When I figured out what is actually wrong with your version I'll update my answer.

**Edit:** Storing both versions in a text file and comparing the actual values written revealed that in your version it's actually not a "C" but another symbol that does look like a "C":
[image: Comparison of HexValues]

Comment: A little poking around suggests that what looks like a `C` in `ActiveColor` is actually a glyph called `Cyrillic Capital Letter Es` by Unicode.

Comment: According to [unicode lookup](https://unicodelookup.com) it should be a `latin capital letter eth` and a `inverted exclamation mark`.
See [0xD0](https://unicodelookup.com/#0xd0) and [0xA1](https://unicodelookup.com/#0xa1/1)

Comment: Now I understand, this is a Cyrillic letter that looks exactly like latin. Symbol "С" (Cyrillic Capital Letter Es) is placed in the same place with "C". Thank You! That You shows me this hidden typo.